# If I have a www domain pointed to Wix, can I point a sub-domain to Heroku and how would that affect SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have my website's `www` domain pointed to a Wix site, but am looking to point a sub-domain to my Heroku app. The domain was purchased from Yahoo Small Business.

i.e. if `www.mysite.com` points to Wix, can `subdomain.mysite.com` point to a heroku app with no issues?

My confusion is because of this line in the Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains):

> Root domains must be added in addition to any subdomains.

Will adding the subdomain to Heroku mess up the domain on Wix somehow?

In addition, would Heroku still be able to automatically handle the SSL certificates etc. if I do direct the sub-domain to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

The quote you reference is in relation to adding root domains. Since you want to point a subdomain at heroku that does not concern you.

The part you are interested in is this part: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain

Basically you want to tell heroku you will add a custom subdomain (follow the instructions) then you need to configure your DNS records to add a CNAME ([this part](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains) gives some examples):

```
Record  Name            Target
CNAME   www             whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com.
CNAME   othersubdomain  autumn-sunset-1495.herokudns.com.
CNAME   examplesecure   example-2121.herokussl.com.
CNAME   examplesecure-eu    example.herokuapp.com.
```